# Run Ant task from Maven

Tags: maven-2, ant

I'm using Ant to build a custom jar library, which then I'm using in Maven as dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>test-lib</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-lib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/test-lib-1.0.0.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

So, basically what I do now is:

1) run ant to build custom library (test-lib-1.0.0.jar)
2) run: mvn compile, to compile my project using custom library among others.

Is there an option for me to do all this (packaing custom jar & compiling project) from
Maven?
I've found maven run plugin, and here are my settings:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>?????what to put here?????/phase>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <ant antfile="${basedir}/build.xml">
                        <target name="prepare-test-lib" />
                    </ant>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But, when running: `mvn compile` it complains about missing artifact: `test-lib-1.0.0.jar`.
I've used compile, generate-resouces,... in `<phase/>` tag, but nothing seems to work.

Is it possible to solve this somehow using this plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the Maven Antrun Plugin, Maven tries to resolve the dependencies to build [ClassPaths](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/examples/classpaths.html) for the AntRun invocation and you thus face a chicken and egg problem : you can't declare a dependency that will be created during AntRun execution that requires this dependency to run. This can't work.

My recommendation would be to mavenize your `test-lib`, to include it in your project build and to declare a regular dependency on it. In other words, what I mean is moving from Ant to Maven to build your `test-lib` and setting up [a multi-modules project](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html). 
To illustrate things more "visually", something like this:

```
my-project
|-- my-module
|   |-- src
|   |   `-- main
|   |       `-- java
|   `-- pom.xml
|-- test-lib
|   |-- src
|   |   `-- main
|   |       `-- java
|   `-- pom.xml
`-- pom.xml
```

Where `my-project/pom.xml` is an aggregating pom with a `<packaging>pom</packaging>` and list the modules under a `<modules>` element:

```
<modules>
  <module>my-module</module>
  <module>test-lib</module>
</modules>
```

And where `my-module/pom.xml` declares a dependency on the `test-lib` artifact:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>your.group.id</groupId>
  <artifactId>test-lib</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm just giving a very high-level overview here, you need to read the documentation a bit for the details, I can't cover everything. Start with the first book from Sonatype (link below).

But that would be the right way to go (and you should just not (ab)use `system` scoped dependencies).

#### References

- [Maven: The Definitive Guide](http://www.sonatype.com/products/maven/documentation/book-defguide)

Comment: Thanx for your answer Pascal! 
Ok, so basically I need to do things differently. But what do you mean by 'mavenize your test-lib'? Do you mean that I should install test-lib on my local maven repository? I tried to avoid this, since test-lib is quite small library, implementing API used in my project, and I want be using it in other projects, for sure.

Comment: @Igor No, I don't mean just installing the test-lib in your local repository, I mean creating a specific maven module and putting the test-lib sources in it (i.e. moving from ant to maven to build it) so that you can include its packaging as part of your build if required (it's IMHO not a problem that it's a small lib, au contraire).

Comment: @Pasacal How can I include test-lib in my project build, and after that to declare standard dependency on it? I would really appreciate if you could point me to some documentation, examples, since I'm quite new to maven. Thanx!

Comment: @Igor: read the free online book: http://www.sonatype.com/products/maven/documentation/book-defguide

Comment: @Igor The link provided by @seanizer (thank you) is definitely a good place to get started. More precisely start with the first book (don't be scared by the word "book").

Comment: @seanizer @Pascal Thanx guys for pointing me in right direction!