# Maven to initate ant task and then using it as dependency

Tags: maven, ant, jar

I have a project which has multiple `.jar` files in it. In the past, I had a `build.xml` file which I was running through `Ant`, and it was creating a new jar out of these multiple jars, and this brand new jar was being referred as a dependency.

Now that I switched to maven, I'd like to know how I can mavenize this. In other words, how to tell maven to build the multiple jars into one jar, and then refer it as a dependency? In order to put things into more solid basis, I'll share the folder structure I have:

```
+- mainProject
+- pom.xml    
+- someGroup
|  +- pom.xml   <- refer here
|  +- sampleModule1
|  | +- pom.xml  <- build here
|  | +- build.xml 
|  | +- first.jar
|  | +- second.jar
```

One idea in my mind is to tell maven to call `build.xml`, which will create that new jar out of those two jars, and then use it as dependency, like here:

```
<dependency>
         <groupId>someGroup</groupId>
         <artifactId>org.boofcv</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0</version>
         <scope>system</scope>
         <systemPath>${project.basedir}/../shared/org.boofcv/brand-new.jar</systemPath>
   </dependency>
```

However, I doubt that it would work, since the chicken-egg problem may occur. By the time I call maven install, the task of creating the new `.jar` may take place after maven looks for it as dependency, resulting an error.

Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Comment: Stop using systemPath...wrong direction. Can you explain what you mean by ` refer here` ? Can you make an example project of your current state and put it on github or so...

Comment: I am using a local repository, and I want to build a jar out of other two jars. Later on I want to use this new jar as dependency. Simple.

Comment: What do you mean by `local repository` ? `$HOME/.m2/repository` ? Building a jar from several jar's can be done via maven-shade-plugin...

Comment: Yes, exactly, I mean `.m2/repository`. And thank you for the direction, if you put this as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: If you using local cache don't use `systemPath` cause it's wrong..

Comment: @khmarbaise I am currently looking for the answer to "how to make a jar out of multiple jars" using maven-shade-plugin. I would be glad if you could answer in this direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching more, I got to know that it is not possible to call an Ant script to build these jars into one jar, and at the same time to tell Maven to use the final jar.  See the below [quote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3506760/6533075):

*"When using the Maven Antrun Plugin, Maven tries to resolve the dependencies to build ClassPaths for the AntRun invocation and you thus face a chicken and egg problem : you can't declare a dependency that will be created during AntRun execution that requires this dependency to run. This can't work."*

instead, I [found out](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/usage.html) a plugin called `maven-shade-plugin`. It creates a one big jar out of small jars, which I can use as dependency later in my top-level `pom.xml`, which was what I asked for.